# How to divorce my husband

Tags: sharia, talaq

Assalamu alaykum!

I'm working in abroad and married, before I came here, the relation between me and my husband was not in good condition, until I found a relationship here and fell in love. I admitted I commit adultery and now I want to divorce my husband.
 What should I do?

Comment: just tell your husband that you no longer wants to be with him. he will definitely give you divorce. by the way this question is not acceptable on this site so i am voting to close it.

Comment: Where is your husband: abroad in the same country or back in home country?

Answer (score 2):

If you don't like your husband, Islam does not force you to live with him. Try talking to your husband and see if he divorces you amicably. If he does not, then if you are in an Islamic country, you can go to court and get khula (annulment of marriage) from court after which you will be free. If you are in a non-Muslim country, take an advice from your local imam and you may have to go through legal system to get a divorce.

As for your adultery, ask forgiveness from Allah (SWT) with an intention of never doing it again and never ever reveal it to anybody because nothing good will ever come out of it. Try to make up for it by doing a lot of good deeds. Allah (SWT) is the most merciful and He will forgive you for your sincere effort. See [Qur'an 39:53](http://quran.com/39/53) and [Qur'an 3:135](http://quran.com/3/135).

My advice to you sister is just be patient, follow through your divorce and remarriage through proper channel following Allah's guidelines and do not fall into sin again.

Comment: On the whole, it would be considered as an appropriate response, and actually you named some suitable advices. Of course in my opinion, you'd better to be patient as much as you can (as the initial step which you'd better attempt to do). Good luck.

Comment: @Naeem, great answer my brother, especially the part about committing adultery and repentance. It seemed that committing adultery was not a concern at all to the OP.