# Can a woman marry another man without being divorced for the first husband?

Tags: nikah, fiqh, talaq

I have been married to a Pakistani man (we did nikah). After some time, I found out that he took another wife. He and his family were treating me very unfairly, insults, etc. They was ringing me to amenice me to leave him. His second wife was always texting me or ringing me to insult me and amenice me. He wasn't by my side, not even one bit. Even he accused me for everything.

I lost my health. I tried to commit suicide so many times, because the pain was so much. I was bullied from every part, and then I met another Pakistani man and I married him without being divorced from the first one.

**Question:** Is the second marriage valid? Or am I still married to the first husband?

Comment: Your 2nd marriage is invalid, and this is haram relationship. You need to be divorced first, then wait until the waiting periode has ended, then and only then an other man can ask you for marriage!

Comment: Some relevant posts https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/30388/13438 and https://islam.stackexchange.com/q/24562/13438

Answer (score -3):

What you are referring to is called Polyandry. there is no specific verse in Quran which states polyandry is forbidden, not that I know of.

but an overwhelming majority of muslim jurists and scholors agree its forbidden because it was never practised during the time of prophet Muhammad pbuh.

You should file for khula in court to make sure you are legally divorced. BTW a marriage is not valid according to Islam, if you were not consented before it. If you were forced to get married to this man, then you should not get a divorce since your marriage is not valid.

Comment: but i already marry the second one without beeing divorce from the 1th husband.so thats means i am still married with the 1th one and the second marriege is not valid?

Comment: yes, the second marriage is not valid, if you married the first one willingly... You have to follow a proper channel. The topic of divorce is discussed in Chapter Anfal. http://www.quran.com/8

Comment: **<comments deleted>** Comments are intended for constructive criticism and seeking clarification for the purposes of improving the post; they are not intended for extended discussion.